# Make the javascript read the value of variable from the PHP

Tags: javascript, php

How do I make the java script read the value of $info ?

```
        $(document).ready( function() {
            $("#anyvalue").focus( function() {
                if ( $(this).val()=="<?php echo $info['anyvalue'];?> ") {
                    $(this).val('');
                } 
            });
        });
```

This code clears the default value of the text when the user clicks on the textbox.

HTML code

```
<input id="anyvalue" type="text" value="<?php echo $detail ['firstname'];?>">
```

Comment: Remove the trailing extra  `space` character after `<?php echo $info['anyvalue'];?>`. Also ask a clear questin. what do u want to do ?

Comment: The JS won't find that because that PHP code is on the server. The JavaScript is looking at the code on the front-end and when the the server code get's sent to the front-end from PHP, it's just regular HTML (no PHP code).

Comment: @Trix What I wanted to do is to clear the value of $info using javascript.

Comment: Using '$(this)' you are referencing to the input '#anyvalue' so when the input has focus does just what you wrote 'empty the value of this input'.

Answer (score 2):

i think you can create a meta tag on your head tag like this

```
<meta id ="anyvalue" data-content="<?php echo $info['anyvalue'];?>">
```

then accessing it using jquery

```
<script>
      $(function() {
         var anyvalue = $('#anyvalue').data('content');
      })
</script>
```

or using vanilla javascript

```
<script>
   var anyvalue = document.getElementById('anyvalue').getAttribute('data-content');
</script>
```

but this is more appropriate rather than echoing data directly to javascript. .

to answer your problem

```
   $(document).ready( function() {
        $("#anyvalueTextField").focus( function() {
            if ( $(this).val() == $('#anyvalue').data('content')) {
                $(this).val('');
            } 
        });
    });
```

Comment: Very nice. Much more organized/semantic than what I've usually seen

Comment: So by using the 'anyvalue' I can now change the value whenever I wanted ?

Comment: it depends on how you will you use it. . my answer is just show how you should pass data from the server to html then accessing it using javascript .. 

if you want to change the value of a field you can use `$(element).val(newValue)` of jquery

Comment: Up vote for both answers. I think this question needs an upvote just sayin :D

Answer (score 0):

You can insert PHP code inside Javascript, but PHP won't be able to read the Javascript variables.

To my understanding, `$info['anyvalue']` must be blank or undefined.

In other words, in your code, the server communicates with the client but the client doesn't communicate with the server.

You have to find another way to exchange data between the client and the server (POST, Ajax, or some trick with PHP nested into Javascript nested into PHP).

Comment: Do you any simpler examples of POST,ajax ?

Comment: Simple but efficient: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ . It will be useful if you want to dynamically change $info['anyvalue'] from Javascript to PHP.

Comment: Is there anything I need to download to use ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: **This is really bad practice**

You can use PHP to initialize a javascript variable if the Javascript code is in your PHP file. So the following would work:

*page.php*

```
<?php $info['anyvalue'] = "foo"; ?>
$(document).ready( function() {
     $("#anyvalue").focus( function() {
         if ( $(this).val()=="<?php echo $info['anyvalue'];?> ") {
            $(this).val('');
         } 
    });
});
```

Since the PHP code will be pre-process before going to the Browser `<?php echo $info['anyvalue'];?>` will become `"foo"`.

But don't do this its messy and not very nice to future developers or your future self, when you have to switch between PHP and JS to track down bugs.

Comment: Why is it a bad practice ? Sorry I am very new learning at javascript.

Comment: Its messy, use noobHere's answer its much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

To parse php inside javascript use single quotes instead of double like:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $("#anyvalue").focus( function() {
            if ( $(this).val()=='<?php echo $info['anyvalue'];?>') {
                $(this).val('');
            } 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain on how does it affect by using single quote please ?